# Patching SharePoint Server 2019 March Security updtes

Tags: cumulative-update, 2019

HI for installing 'Description of the security update for SharePoint Server 2019: March 12, 2019 KB 4462199;2019 Is we need to patch first below patches that has language pack updates also?
currently, we have already installed January patches in this Sharepoint farm?

February 12, 2019, update for SharePoint Server 2019 Language Pack (KB4462170)
Description of the security update for SharePoint Server 2019: February 12, 2019 KB 4462171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to apply the latest non-language and language dependent fixes. Since March did not have a language-dependent fix, you will need to apply the Feb 2019 language-dependent fix.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462170/february-12-2019-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-language-pack-kb446

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462199/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-march-12

Comment: There are January 2019 Updates already installed in my farm again i will go for Feb 2019 updates and install March 2019 updates that have no language pack updates?